# How to get the checked atribute of a checkbox with javascript

Tags: javascript, checkbox, checked, inline-editing

I'm following this tutorial on inline editing, http://www.datatables.net/blog/Inline_editing.

Now I come up with problem, I'm trying to edit checkboxes and I'm not getting there.

I simply replaced inputs of type text with checkbox, but I guess there's more to it. So my question is, how can I read the checked attribute of a checkbox?

This is my code

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    function restoreRow(oTable, nRow) {
        var aData = oTable.fnGetData(nRow);
        var jqTds = $('>td', nRow);

        for (var i = 0, iLen = jqTds.length; i < iLen; i++) {
            oTable.fnUpdate(aData[i], nRow, i, false);
        }

        oTable.fnDraw();
    }

    function editRow(oTable, nRow) {
        var aData = oTable.fnGetData(nRow);
        var jqTds = $('>td', nRow);
        jqTds[0].innerHTML = '<input type="text" value="' + aData[0] + '">';
        jqTds[1].innerHTML = '<input type="text" value="' + aData[1] + '">';
        jqTds[2].innerHTML = '<input type="checkbox" value="' + aData[2] + '">';
        jqTds[3].innerHTML = '<a class="edit" href="">Save</a>';

    }

    function saveRow(oTable, nRow) {
        var jqInputs = $('input', nRow);
        oTable.fnUpdate(jqInputs[0].value, nRow, 0, false);
        oTable.fnUpdate(jqInputs[1].value, nRow, 1, false);
        oTable.fnUpdate('<input type="checkbox" checked="' + jqInputs[2].value + '">', nRow, 2, false);
        oTable.fnUpdate('<a class="edit" href="">Edit</a>', nRow, 3, false);
        oTable.fnDraw();
    }

    $(document).ready(function () {
        var oTable = $('#tbl').dataTable();
        var nEditing = null;

        $('#new').click(function (e) {
            e.preventDefault();

            var aiNew = oTable.fnAddData(['', '', '',
            '<a class="edit" href="">Edit</a>', '<a class="delete" href="">Delete</a>']);
            var nRow = oTable.fnGetNodes(aiNew[0]);
            editRow(oTable, nRow);
            nEditing = nRow;
        });

        $('#tbl a.delete').live('click', function (e) {
            e.preventDefault();

            var nRow = $(this).parents('tr')[0];
            oTable.fnDeleteRow(nRow);
        });

        $('#tbl a.edit').live('click', function (e) {
            e.preventDefault();

            /* Get the row as a parent of the link that was clicked on */
            var nRow = $(this).parents('tr')[0];

            if (nEditing !== null && nEditing != nRow) {
                /* Currently editing - but not this row - restore the old before continuing to edit mode */
                restoreRow(oTable, nEditing);
                editRow(oTable, nRow);
                nEditing = nRow;
            }
            else if (nEditing == nRow && this.innerHTML == "Save") {
                /* Editing this row and want to save it */
                saveRow(oTable, nEditing);
                nEditing = null;
            }
            else {
                /* No edit in progress - let's start one */
                editRow(oTable, nRow);
                nEditing = nRow;
            }
        });
    });
```

And this is my table

```
<p>
                    <a id="new" href="">Add new row</a></p>
                <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" class="tbl" id="tbl">
                    <thead>
                        <tr>
                            <th>
                                Name
                            </th>
                            <th>
                                Description
                            </th>
                            <th>
                                Sample
                            </th>
                            <th>
                            </th>
                            <th>
                            </th>
                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>
                        @if (Model != null)
                        {
                            foreach (var item in Model.TestFields)
                            { 
                            <tr>
                                <td>
                                    @Truncate(item.Name, 20)
                                </td>
                                <td>
                                    @Truncate(item.Description, 20)
                                </td>
                                <td>
                                    @Html.CheckBoxFor(i => item.Sample)
                                </td>
                                <td>
                                    <a class="edit" href="">Edit</a>
                                </td>
                                <td>
                                    <a class="delete" href="">Delete</a>
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                            }
                        }
                    </tbody>
                </table>
```

Comment: `if (checkboxElement.checked) { ... }`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should solve your problem for many selected checkboxs

```
// #BoxWrapper is supposed to be the div that contains the checkbox this could be replaced            
// by $(document) if you are not using a div as a container. 
$("#BoxWrapper").find('input:checkbox').each(function(){
var checked = $(this).attr('checked');
if(checked){
 //here you do what needs to be done for checked ones
}
});
```

Comment: Based on your solution, I came up with this which is what I need.        var $checkbox = $(nRow).find('input:checkbox');
jqTds[2].innerHTML = '<input type="checkbox" checked="' + $checkbox.attr('checked') + '">';                                      Tks.

Comment: I am glad that solved your problem, you are more than welcome.

Comment: and declare: var jqTds = $('>td', nRow);  within the saveRow function.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your `$` symbol is jQuery, you can do this :

```
$('#my_checkbox').is(':checked') // true if my_checkbox is checked, false otherwise.
```

Comment: BUt I don't have just one checkbox, I can have 100 or more. And I access the checkboxes through this code,  jqTds[2].innerHTML = '<input type="checkbox" value="' + aData[2] + '">';,  Being aData[2] one checkbox.